# Cartesian product of regular expressions?

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

My textbook has a problem to find the regular expression that describes the set of all strings of `0`'s and `1`'s whose number of `0`'s is divisible by `5` and whose number of `1`'s is even.

I can write a regular expression for each condition

a. $0^*(10^*1)^*$

b. $1^*(01^*01^*01^*01^*01^*)^*$

I am having trouble understanding how to combine these two regular expressions. If they were DFAs, I could combine them by taking their cartesian product. Is is possible to take the cartesian product of two regular expressions (without translating each to a DFA first)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665392/regular-expression-for-strings-with-even-number-of-1s-and-number-of-0s-divisib

Comment: Converting to a DFA first is the most natural way to take their intersection (product).

Comment: The first regular expression is wrong.

Comment: This is answered on [math.se]: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/913165/1277.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gelade and Neven prove the following theorem in their paper [Succinctness of the Complement and Intersection of
Regular Expressions](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00226864/document):

> For every $n$ there exist two regular expressions $r_1,r_2$ of size $O(n^2)$ such that the smallest regular expression representing $L[r_1] \cap L[r_2]$ has size $\Omega(2^n)$.

This suggests that there is no analog of the product construction for regular expressions.